# TypeScript: Create An Object Of An Arbitrary Type From A Function Parameter Without Using 'Any' or 'Unknown'

Tags: typescript, validation, generics, types

I have a `type` that describes errors in a Location form. Each field of the Location form can have an error, reported as a string. The `type` is defined as such:

```
 type LocationFormErrors = {
    name: string,
    description: string,
 }
```

I'm using a validation function that passes the form object to be validated plus a map describing the validations to perform, as such:

```
const validate = (location: Location) => {
    let errors: LocationFormErrors = validateFormObject<Location, LocationFormErrors>(
      location,
      {
        name: {
          length: [3, 20]
        },
        description: {
          length: [3, 20]
        },
      }
    );
    return errors;
 }
```

I would like the object returned to the `errors` variable to be of the `type` provided, in this case `LocationFormErrors`. This is the generic validation function (`U` is the arbitrary `type` to use for the form errors object):

```
export const validateFormObject = <T, U>(formObject: T, validationMap: ValidationMap):U => {
  let errors: U = {}; 
  ...
  return errors;
}
```

However, this causes the following error:

`'U' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '{}'.`

Is there any possible way to create the `errors` object in `validate()` with arbitrary `type` `U` in a way that makes the compiler happy?

I know I could use `any` or `unknown`, but I'm trying to avoid those to keep with TypeScript best practices.

Any advice would be appreciated!

**EDIT:** I am still seeking answers that are "more correct" than this, but I was able to reach the desired functionality by casting first as `unknown` and then as arbitrary `type` "U"

`return (errors as unknown) as U`

Comment: If I guess correctly, you mean that LocationForm has 2 fields `name` and `description`? And the LocationFormErrors type reflects these 2 fields as well?

Comment: Exactly, yes -- they are named the same, but are technically different "Types"